# EF Core rewrite the query in a form that can be translated after upgrading

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

This query was working fine before we upgraded:

```
var appUsers = await _masterDbContext
                      .Users
                      .Include(x => x.UserCustomers)
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Select(AppUserDto.Projection)
                      .Where(user => !user.IsDeleted && user.UserCustomers.Any(x => x.CustomerId == tenant.Id && x.UserId == user.Id))
                      .DistinctBy(x => x.Id)
                      .ToDataSourceResultAsync(request.GridOptions, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

We're now getting the error:

```
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, 
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 
'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

It appears that the DistinctBy is the offender but being fairly new to LINQ I can't figure out how to rewrite it so that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `DistinctBy` to `Distinct()` and move that and the predicate before the `Select`.  I also shifted the `AsNoTracking()` up:

```
var appUsers = await _masterDbContext
    .Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.UserCustomers)
    .Where(user => 
        !user.IsDeleted 
        && user.UserCustomers
            .Any( x => x.CustomerId == tenant.Id ) )
    .Distinct()
    .Select(AppUserDto.Projection)
    .ToDataSourceResultAsync(request.GridOptions, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: This worked but I had to move the AsNoTracking under Users or VS would complain.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks you have upgraded from EF Core 2.x, which loads full filtered set into the memory. `DistinctBy` is not translatable by EF Core 6.

Try the following solution:

```cs
var filtered = _masterDbContext.Users
    .Select(AppUserDto.Projection)
    .Where(user => !user.IsDeleted && user.UserCustomers.Any(x => x.CustomerId == tenant.Id && x.UserId == user.Id));

var query = 
    from d in filtered.Select(d => new { d.Id }).Distinct()
    from u in filtered.Where(u => u.Id == d.Id).Take(1)
    select u;

var appUsers = await query.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request.GridOptions, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Trying this but getting the following error:

"Translation of 'EF.Property<string>(default(AppUser), \"Id\")' failed. 
Either the query source is not an entity type, or the specified property does not exist on the entity type."

Comment: Looks like your `AppUserDto.Projection` is not suitabke for SQL.